# git log -s returns blank on file that isn't in repository

Tags: git

In a git repository, running the commands

```
touch fileName
git log -s fileName
```

returns blank, but

```
git log -s anotherFilename
```

indicates that anotherFilename is not in the repository.

Why would git log return an indicator that the file isn't in the repository?

What git command, when run on a file in the filesystem, would return

```
file checked in - return log
file not committed/staged - return error
file does not exist - return another error
```

Overall I'm not sure why a git file status command on a file would just created return anything but an error.

Comment: I've never run `git log -s`, but it sounds to me like maybe you really want to be using `git status` here.

Comment: The `-s` bit is unimportant to the question, it just mutes the diff output in the default `git log`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file isn't present in the file system then `git log` can't figure out if the file name is a missing file or an invalid option. Use the "--" option-to-file separator (`git log -s -- anotherFilename`) to remove the ambiguity and the error about "unknown revision or path not in the working tree" will go away.

This is documented in `git log --help`:

> Paths may need to be prefixed with ‘`-- '’ to separate them from options or the revision range, when confusion arises.

Answer (score 1):

Besides [Paul Hicks' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46923538/1256452) (correct and upvoted), note that `git log` is not about showing *file* status, it's about selecting and showing *commits*.  There are a few special cases where "select commit based on file" results in something that could be called "file status" but that's an effect, rather than the purpose of the command.

To test whether the file is present in a specific commit, use `git rev-parse`:

```
git rev-parse HEAD:dir/file.txt
```

for instance.  It will either succeed, printing the hash ID of the file in the specified commit, or fail, printing an error message.  (Add `-q --verify` before the commit-and-path to avoid the error message, and get the result of the test as the stdout and exit status of `git rev-parse`.)

To test whether the file is in the staging area, you can use `git rev-parse` again, using the special `:stage-number:path` syntax:

```
git rev-parse :0:dir/file.txt
```

As before, `-q --verify` modify the behavior on error:

```
$ git rev-parse :0:Makefile
b143e4eea3fa75eebd883361c40c3faa9e6c8060
$ git rev-parse :0:not-in-index
:0:not-in-index
fatal: Path 'not-in-index' does not exist (neither on disk nor in the index).
$ git rev-parse -q --verify :0:not-in-index
$ echo $?
1
```

You can also use `git ls-files --stage -- <path>` to check for active merge conflicts:

```
$ git ls-files --stage -- Makefile
100644 b143e4eea3fa75eebd883361c40c3faa9e6c8060 0       Makefile
```

In the case of a merge conflict (there is none here), you will see entries for stages 1, 2, and/or 3, whose hash IDs you could extract again with `git rev-parse` but using `:1:path`, `:2:path`, and `:3:path`.

To test whether the file is in the work-tree, use ordinary utilities, since the work-tree contains ordinary files in their ordinary format that your computer uses every day (as opposed to the special gitty formats for committed and staged files).

Note that whether or not the file is present in the index and/or staging area, it may or may not exist in various commits.  For instance, in the Git repository for Git itself, `builtin-apply.c` is long gone, but:

```
$ git log --oneline -- builtin-apply.c
81b50f3ce Move 'builtin-*' into a 'builtin/' subdirectory
9517e6b84 Typofixes outside documentation area
41905647f Merge branch 'ag/patch-header-verify'
df91d0e4d Merge branch 'ag/maint-apply-too-large-p'
[mass snippage]
```

(the file is now named `builtin/apply.c`).